# Affine transformation model using RANSAC

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, affinetransform, homography, matlab-cvst

I am trying to estimate homography between 2 images using only three correspondences using RANSAC ie I am trying to find Affine transformation  connecting the two images . The approach
I am using is take the SVD of the data matrix(made using three correspondences) and then take the last column of the v in ([u,s,v]=SVD(A)) as homography matrix and then use RANSAC approach to get the best fit Homography matrix.  I am trying to use this code :

http://www.vlfeat.org/applications/sift-mosaic-code.html

Could anybody please tell me how to get affine transformation Homography matrix ?

Comment: I want to implement the thing in matlab

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox you can use the `estimateGeometricTransform` function.

Comment: :thanks , I will try looking into it.But is there any other method purely mathematically solvable ?

Answer (score 0):

why are you using RANSAC and SVD if you have only three points? the purpose of both, is to find the best fit in case of possible false matches, or if you have many matches, respectively.

you should try [getAffineTransform()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#getaffinetransform), the link also gives an overview of how this function works so incase you are not looking for opencv library you can get an idea and implement you own.